# android load library specified version instead of generic version library

Tags: android, libcurl

I've built successfully my android app using libcurl.
But I could not load my program. The error message that I've received is:

> Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not
>   load library "libcurl.so.5" needed by "mylib.so"; caused by
>   load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "libcurl.so.5" not found

In my program, I've got only libcurl.so file. I tried to use only libcurl.so file (remove libcurl.so.5 file and recompile). But the loading error is still existing.

I saw inside the .apk file, there is only libcurl.so file. I think my problem is mylib refer to libcurl.so.5 somewhere. But after delete libcurl.so.5, recompile, the error is remaining. How to make mylib.so depend libcurl.so, not depend libcurl.so.5 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's crazy. I've modified the config file by removing all major tag in config file. 
Now, at least, it works.